# Get files in a directory calling into native code from .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to call into native code to get the files in a directory.  Anyone know what library I could use to do this?  I.e. something like GetDirectories (but not .net).

Comment: Why must you use native code?

Comment: This seems like an awfully contrived requirement. Care to explain the need for this?

Comment: You are already in .NET, so why would using the built-in libraries be a problem?

Comment: Because there's a large memory leak when using GetFiles/GetDirectories/EnumerateDirectories/EnumerateFiles over a folder that contains 500,000+ files. When using ONLY (meaning there's no other code in the application) the code below (over these folders which contain 300+ GB of files), I lose a GB or more of memory permanently until the system is rebooted.

Comment: List<string> list = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("F:\\Video","*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

Comment: It might not be a memory leak though.  Maybe calling these .net routines desribed above causes the CLR to cache something, but doing it with a bunch of files causes lots of memory to be "lost" (so usually it's not noticed?)

Comment: The problem was with the file cache feature of windows.  It was causing 2 GB of memory to be taken up when simply walking a directory tree.

Comment: Fixing the "leak" is simple: just don't call `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [FindNextFile](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FindNextFile.html) and related Win32 methods - check [File Management Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

http://PInvoke.net is the site that contains many PInvoke calls - likely you'll fined the rest there too.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Andrew, I'm not sure what type of "native" you mean, but you could use the **Windows Scripting Host (WSH)** (called the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" on the "COM" tab when adding a reference) `FileSystemObject`:

```
Dim fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject()

For Each file As Scripting.File In fso.GetFolder("c:\").Files
    'do whatever you need here, e.g.:
    MsgBox(file.Path)
Next
```

Comment: I suspect the questioner means "native" in the sense of the Win32 C API via P/Invoke. WSH isn't native in that sense.